# Recursive succ addition in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, addition, successor-arithmetics

```
add(0,Y,Y).
add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)) :-
        add(X,Y,Z).
```

I don't understand how this one works.
If I run the query:

```
add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R)
```

How does it remove succ from the first argument?

If I run it:

```
X=succ(succ(succ(0)))
Y=succ(succ(0))
R=?
```

This satisfied the body. We input them into the head:

```
add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)) %% becomes
add(succ(succ(succ(0))),succ(succ(0)),succ(R))
```

I.e. it looks to me as if it just adds succ, not removes them from the first argument? I saw that there's another post about this exact question but it does not make sense to me.

Comment: Tha pattern matching on the second clause will set `X = succ(succ(0))`, so here you "unpack" the functor.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the goal `add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R)` and Prolog tries to execute the clause with the head `add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z))`, *unification* happens. Unification is one of the central concepts of Prolog, and it's important to understand it well. Unification is also the operation that is performed by the `=` operator. What happens when the head of the clause is executed is exactly the same as happens when you execute the following equivalent query:

```
?- add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R) = add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)).
```

It is important to understand that unification is not just "unpacking" or "building up" terms, but *both at the same time*.

It can "extract" information from terms:

```
?- X = f(a), Y = f(Z), X = Y.
X = Y, Y = f(a),
Z = a.
```

Here we found that `a` is the argument of the `f` functor in `X`.

It can "construct" terms:

```
?- X = f(Y), Y = g(h).
X = f(g(h)),
Y = g(h).
```

Here we "inserted" the term `g(h)` into the "hole" `Y` in `X`.

It can also do both at the same time to more than one term:

```
?- X = f(a, B), Y = f(A, b), X = Y.
X = Y, Y = f(a, b),
B = b,
A = a.
```

Here unification "unpacked" both `f` terms, then "filled in" a hole in each of them.

Now, armed with this knowledge, what does the unification in your example do?

```
?- add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R) = add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)).
R = succ(Z),
X = Y, Y = succ(succ(0)).
```

In particular, when `succ(succ(succ(0)))` is unified with `succ(X)`, this will bind `X` to `succ(succ(0))`. `X` is *not* bound to the entire term `succ(succ(succ(0)))` but only to an "inner" part. This is what removes one level of `succ` from the argument.